# Ruffini's rule help

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$$R(x) = 2x^2+x-1, s=-3; \implies 2x^3+3x^2-4 = (2x^2+x-1)(x+1) - 3$$

I saw this on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule#Polynomial_division_by_x_.E2.88.92_r).

I do not understand what's happening here
$$ 
s=-3;\quad \Rightarrow 2x^{3}+3x^{2}-4=(2x^{2}+x-1)(x+1)-3\!
$$

Hopefully someone can explain it.

If this is wrong I appreciate if someone can tell me.

Comment: Thanks, @rubik, for making the Question more self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $P$ is a polynomial and $P(x_0)=y_0$ then $P(x_0)-y_0=0$ and by [Ruffini's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule), the polynomial $P-y_0$ is divisible by $x-x_0$, that is $P(x)=Q(x)(x-x_0)+y_0$ for some polynomial $Q$.

In your case $P(x)=2x^{3}+3x^{2}-4$, $P(-1)=-3$  and $P(x)=(2x^{2}+x-1)(x+1)-3$.

Answer (score 0):

They were dividing $2x^3+3x^2-4$ by $(x+1)$. The statement is that the quotient polynomial is $(2x^2+x-1)$ remainder polynomial and the remainder (which they have called $s$) is $-3$.

BTW, your link did not work for me.

Comment: Link should work now